# How to encrypt my windows 10 system partition ? On a tablet

Tags: windows-10, encryption

I have a tablet with dualboot, android and windows 10. For some reasons (eg. if my tablet becomes stolen), I'd like to encrypt my windows 10 partition.
I know truecrypt and veracrypt but they add a bootloader in which I cannot use the touchscreen to enter the password.

My windows version is Home then bitlocker is not installed. And I do not want to buy Win 10 Pro just to use bitlocker.

Is there any alternative ?

I read somewhere, win 10 Home could read bitlocker partition but not encrypt them. Should I use a Win10 Pro to encrypt my partition and replace it into my tablet ?

My tablet is GPT and UEFI.

Edit: I'll need something like `eCryptfs` for ubuntu. Everything is transparent.

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't have any encryption solutions except what is called device encryption since it's a tablet.  Windows EFS and Bitlocker cannot be used on Windows 10 home. Since your using GPT programs like TrueCrypt cannot be used

Answer (score 0):

It might be doable.

First off,

> I read somewhere, win 10 Home could read bitlocker partition but not encrypt them. Should I use a Win10 Pro to encrypt my partition and replace it into my tablet?

This wont work.  Yes, Windows Home can read bitlocker encrypted drives, but Windows has to be *booted* to mount the drive.

Here is an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/287071/can-bitlocker-be-used-in-a-dual-boot-system-with-windows-on-one-drive-linux-on) for the same question for Linux that *may* work for you.  I would expect it to work with Android.  Depending on whether or not you have a TPM will determine the method.

Comment: Thank but I still need Win10 `pro` since I don't have Bitlocker on my `home` version. I thought the advantage of Bitlocker was to encrypt everything except the minimum required files to boot and run windows. Kind of transparent behavior, decrypt everything when I log in. As Android does. Android shouldn't be a problem, I don't have data I need to protect and if so, Android provides an integrated encryption system.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP ah.  if its just data, why not use EFS?

Comment: Because I'd like to encrypt the whole user data folder. Want to set it once at the boot and forget it. It's only to protect my applications (firefox, edge, other software) data against theft. For firefox, I could create a container and move the profile folder.  But for other ones...

Comment: What you want to do requires Windows 10 Professional